# Execute function before render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How do I ensure a function is executed before my `render()`? I have `this.getIssueButtonCollection()` inside my `componentDidMount()`. `this.getIssueButtonCollection()` in turn calls `getIssueDoc()` which updates interface `this.issues.issueDoc` value that is used by an element in my `render()`. Currently my element gets this as `undefined`.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Comment: Your render function will be called again after state updates. use `setState` instead of local class properties.